# requestRecordPermission not working in ios10 xcode 8 beta 3

Tags: swift, avfoundation, swift3, ios10, xcode8

when I try to request permission to record with the mic it throws **" [access] < private>"**

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
        if granted {

            print("yass")
        } else {
            print("Permission to record not granted")
        }
    })
```

Anybody got a workaround?
This works with 7.3 tho

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the output log looks like this:

```
2016-07-08 16:41:11.268943 project-name[362:56625] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-07-08 16:41:11.272276 project-name[362:56625] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2016-07-08 16:41:11.356590 project-name[362:56700] [access] <private>
```

You might be missing permissions for camera usage.

The solution is to add the "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" key to your Info.plist.

[image: Picture of my plist that works]

[Here's a link to an Apple Developer Forum discussion explaining why this occurs.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51239)

Comment: This only partially answers the question - please keep discussion such as this in the comments.

Comment: @techydesigner this is my first time answering a SO question. Could/would you provide more information about what is missing in the spirit of participation? I believe I'm pointing out a symptom of the error (the printed log) and a potential fix.

Comment: Whilst true, please make our clear that your fix only works in a certain scenario.